# Recommendation for a Software product catalog framework?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, shopping-cart, catalog

Following is the requirement, in broad terms:

- An online catalog for Softwares developed by a group of
  organizations. The initial number of items in the catalog is in low
  hundreds, but there's a potential for growth - both in the number of
  organizations & the products
- The catalog should support the basic features like: product
  description, screenshots, categories/tags, couple of standard payment
  gateways, reviews, customer ratings, feedbacks, share to social media
  networks
- Programmer-friendly - easy to customize, extend, modify etc; preferably in PHP / Ruby on Rails
- other 'nice-to-haves': templates, themes

Of course I Googled for such frameworks and came across the following:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/  - PHP
- http://www.shopify.com/          - Ruby on Rails
- http://spreecommerce.com/buzz    - Ruby on Rails
- http://www.phpmydirectory.com/   - PHP
- Customize a CMS system like Joomla or Drupal

Before I actually try them out, I would like to hear the experience/recommendation of others. Have you used any of the above or other similar frameworks? Which one would you recommend for the above requirement, based on cost vs features, considering that those who are setting up the catalog are Small & Medium Enterprises (SME) / independent freelancers? Are you aware of any other framework which suits my requirement better?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [BigCommerce.com](http://above.bigcommerce.com) to that list.

It integrates with a huge range of 3rd party payment gateways, shipping vendors, accounting software, mailing list sites etc

We are a web design company and used to use Magento and osCommerce for our clients needs but since trialing BigCommerce out, we are hooked - so much we use it exclusively for any new ecommerce jobs.

It takes all the headaches out of management as it's already hosted and supported for you and no need to fumble around with addons/plugins that could break your site, as it comes with just about everything you could imagine.

If you know basic HTML/CSS you can easily get in there and edit any of the 90+ inbuilt templates, but they have a developer network if you need further customisation. Starts at $24.95/mth Definitely worth a look!

Comment: On further investigation (and based on recommendation from other experts outside SO), that was my choice too! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

its best to go with your own needs as lot of people might recommend things that you might not like. most open source products are written in php and are easy to code but also there are many plugins/addons available for free to customise further whatever you choose.

go here to try out different demo's for yourself.

[open source demo](http://php.opensourcecms.com/scripts/show.php?catid=3&category=eCommerce)